# Check if any NavigationLink is active

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have many NavigationLinks in my NavigationView, and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of seeing if any of them are active, compared to attaching individual isActive booleans to each and monitor when a single on is active.

Comment: `NavigationStack` in iOS 16 lets you populate a path

Comment: If I may ask : why do you need this ?